# Adding multiple Panels and events to a GUI

Tags: java, swing, events, mouseevent, jtextfield

I'm new to java and working on a GUI assignment and I'm running into some issues.  The premise is a simple GUI window that has a few mouse events and a few keyboard events.

I put together a window with some mouse events and once that was working started to add a couple JTextFields to the window but they're not showing up on the window and I'm not exactly sure why.

**Here is the problem now.  I created a new panel (panel2) to add the JTextFields to the window and I now see the JTextFields but it overtakes the entire window and the Mouse Events do not work with it.  If I add the JTF to the panel above the Mouse Events then the JTF do not show up and the Mouse Events work.......**

code

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

    public class EventDemo extends JFrame {

        private JPanel mousePanel;
        private JPanel panel1;
        private JPanel panel2;
        private JPanel panel3;
        private JLabel statusBar;
        private JLabel directions1;
        private JLabel directions2;
        private JLabel directions3;
        private JTextField textField1;
        private JTextField textField2;

    public EventDemo() {
        super("EVENT DEMO PROGRAM");

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel2 = new JPanel();

    //Add directions for the events to top of the window.
    directions1 = new JLabel("Enter & Leave window." + 
                            "    Press & hold, release, drag, move cursor to display a message in statusbar." + 
                            "    Clicking in one spot will display coordinates.");  
    panel1.add(directions1);
    add(panel1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);   

    //Add mouse and statusBar to panel.
    mousePanel = new JPanel();
    mousePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
    add(mousePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);   
    statusBar = new JLabel("Default");
    add(statusBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //Create handler object for Mouse events
    TheHandler handler = new TheHandler();
    mousePanel.addMouseListener(handler);
    mousePanel.addMouseMotionListener(handler); 


    textField1 = new JTextField(10);
    panel2.add(textField1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    textField2 = new JTextField("Enter Text Here");
    panel2.add(textField2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(panel2);

    TheHandler handlerJTF = new TheHandler();
    textField1.addActionListener(handlerJTF);
    textField2.addActionListener(handlerJTF); 


    }

    private class TheHandler implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            statusBar.setText(String.format("YOU CLICKED THE MOUSE AT %d, %d", event.getX(), event.getY()));
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            statusBar.setText("YOU HAVE PRESSED THE MOUSE BUTTON.");
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
            statusBar.setText("YOU HAVE RELEASED THE MOUSE BUTTON.");
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
            statusBar.setText("YOU HAVE ENTERED THE WINDOW THE BACKGROUND CHANGES TO RED.");
            mousePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
            statusBar.setText("EXITING THE WINDOW, BACKGROUND CHANGES BACK TO WHITE.");
            mousePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }

        //Mouse Motion events.
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            statusBar.setText("YOU ARE DRAGGING THE MOUSE.");
        }
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
            statusBar.setText("YOU ARE MOVING THE MOUSE AROUND.");
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        textField1.getText();
        textField2.getText();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventDemo go = new EventDemo();
        go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        go.setSize(960, 300);
        go.setVisible(true);
        new EventDemo();

    }
    }
```

Comment: `TheHandler` does not `implement` `ActionListener` which is the required type of `JTextField#addActionListener`.  See [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) for  more details

Comment: Oh ok, duh!  Thank you!  Why are the JTextFields not showing up on the window though?

Comment: Yep, just saw that, sorry.  I'm half blind from starring at my computer for about 7 hours straight haha.  Thanks again!

Comment: No worries, sometimes it can take a couple of minutes for updates to flow through ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `TheHandler` does not `implement` `ActionListener` which is the required type of `JTextField#addActionListener`.  See [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) for  more details
2. Your `actionPerformed` method isn't actually defined in `TheHandler` class, but is a method of the `EventDemo` class
3. You should use the `@Override` annotation when you think you're overriding methods (or implementing methods from an `interface`) as this will cause a compiler error when you're wrong (for some reason)
4. Your fields aren't appearing for two reasons, first, `textField` is added to `panel2` which is never added to anything and `textField2` is been added to the frame (at the default position of `BorderLayout.CENTER`), but is been overriden/circumvented by `add(mousePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);`, so it's actually never laid out by the frames `BorderLayout`.  Have a look at [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details

Comment: Yeah I think my main issue is I'm confused about the layout and where everything is going.  It took me for ever to get the JLabel at the top of the window and I had to condense it to one line essentially.  I'll read through that article and see if I can figure it out, thank you

Comment: So I just turned my assignment in as is without the JTextFields on the panel because I was out of time.  I'd like to learn how to add multiple items to the panel, the link you gave me seems more about boarders then layout.  Is there something else you could point me to so I can learn how toads multiple things better?  I had a seperate assignment where I had multiple JTextFields but there were no mouse events so I thinking the mouse events inturupted the text fields from being added to the panel?

Comment: You could add both fields to the `panel2` (which is using a `FlowLayout`) and add `panel2` to the `BorderLayout.SOUTH` position of the frame

Comment: That works by adding the JTF to the window but...Here is the problem now. I added the JTextFields to the window with panel2 and I now see the JTextFields but it overtakes the entire window and the Mouse Events do not work with it. If I add the JTF to the panel above the Mouse Events then the JTF do not show up and the Mouse Events work.......

Comment: To which part of `BorderLayout` did you add the text field's panel?

Comment: To the SOUTH like you suggested.  The original code was updated with the changes.  Did I explain what was happening in a way that made sense?  It's a little hard to explain...

Comment: `add(panel2);` isn't adding `panel2` to the `SOUTH` position of the frame, but now you have the `statusBar` there instead :P.  You could create another panel, maybe using a `GridLayout` and combine the `panel1` and `panel2` into it (adding the resulting `JPanel` to the `NORTH` position), but that all depends on where you want things to be added

Comment: Oh yeah you're right!  I completely forgot I had the statusBar in the SOUTH position.  I was honestly just trying to make it all work and didn't really care where it all went.  The mouseEvents essentially, one changes the background color when the mouse moves in or out of the window and if you click or drag, etc, in the window it displays a message in the statusBar, I had to limit the "directions" to one line otherwise it took up the entire window no matter how big I made it and the mouse events didn't work and it's the same with the JTF, if I add them the mouse events don't work.

Comment: I think I need to learn more about Layout / GridLayout / BorderLayout...Any recommendations on which to start with and a good tutorial to watch or read up on that?